# IndexError: index 132 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 132 [NUMPY]

Tags: python, numpy

Estoy haciendo una IA que predice el valor de los grados que introduzcas en Celsius para pasarlos a Fahrenheit y a la hora de establecer los arrays equivalentes para entrenarla tengo un problema con el segundo

```
celsius = np.array([-30, -29, -28, -27, -26, -25, -24, -23, -22, -21, -20, -19, -18, -17, -16, -15, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86 ,87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104], dtype=float)
fahrenheit = np.array([-22, -20.2, -18.4, -16.6, -14.8, 13, -11.2, -9.4, -7.6, -5.8, -4, -2.2, -0.4, 1.4, 3.2, 5, 6.8, 8.6, 10.4, 12.2, 14, 15.8, 17.6, 19.4, 21.2, 23, 24.8, 26.6, 28.4, 30.2, 32, 33.8, 35.6, 37.4, 39.2, 41, 42.8, 44.6, 46.4, 48.2, 50, 51.8, 53.6, 55.4, 57.2, 59, 60.8, 62.6, 64.4, 66.2, 68, 69.8, 71.6, 73.4, 75.2, 77, 78.8, 80.6, 82.4, 84.2, 86, 87.8, 89.6, 91.4, 93.2, 95, 96.8, 98.6, 100.4, 102.2, 104, 105.8, 107.6, 109.4, 111.2, 113, 114.8, 116.6, 118.4, 120.2, 122, 123.8, 125.6, 127.4, 129.2, 131, 132.8, 134.6, 138.2, 140, 141.8, 143.6, 145.4, 147.2, 149, 150.8, 152.6, 158, 159.8, 161.6, 163.4, 165.2, 167, 168.8, 170.6, 172.4, 174.2, 176, 177.8, 179.6, 181.4, 183.2, 185, 186.8, 188.6, 190.4, 192.2, 194, 195.8, 197.6, 199.4, 201.2, 203, 204.8, 206.6, 208.4, 210.2, 212, 213.8, 215.6, 217.4, 219.2], dtype=float)

for i,c in enumerate(celsius):
  print('{} degrees celsius = {} degrees fahrenheit'.format(c,fahrenheit[i]))

IndexError: index 132 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 132
```

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: celsius tiene 135 elementos, y fahrenheit sólo 132. ¿Está correcto esto?

Comment: Es posible que sea ese el problema. Volveré a comprobarlo. Muchas gracias!!